# CouchDB write/read only (no edit) user

Tags: python, django, nosql, couchdb, python-cloudant

### Toolchain/frameworks

I'm using `django==2.1.3` and `python-cloudant==2.1.3` and running `CouchDB ver. 2.2.0`, and pretty much doing all of my setup/configuration through `Fauxton`. I like to think that I know my way around python/django in general, and I'm testing this approach in a small little project to see how it works

### Problem Description

Suppose I have a fairly simple CRUD application with just 1 model:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    asset_id = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

and I have a view that I use to create the asset

```
class CreateAssetView(views.View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #some code here


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #some code here|
        #log request data into database
        client = CouchDB('myusername', 'mypassword', url='http://127.0.0.1:5984', connect=True)
        db = client['assets']

        log_data = {'view_name': self.view_name, 'post_data': post_data,'user': request.user.username,
                    'time': str(timezone.now())}
        db.create_document(log_data)
        return render(...)
```

I understand that I should be doing the logging portion using a middleware (which I plan to) and probably just use django's `CreateView` in that case, I'm doing this approach for now just during early development.

What I'm having a problem wrapping my head around is creating a user with `myusername` and `mypassword` that has the permissions to:

1. Write new documents
2. Read old documents
3. **not edit** already created documents

I could even settle for 1 and 3 only (and only use admin to read). I spent a little bit of time playing around with `Fauxton`'s interface for permissions, but I can only basically create a `user` and assign a `role` (couldn't even get to assigning a password :/)

**clarification**

The `Asset` is not a `CouchDB` document, that's a normal SQL model, I only want to dump the logs with post data to `CouchDB`

Any help/gudiance/documentation pointers would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Overview

Couchdb has one overriding level of [administrator setup in configuration](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html?highlight=users%20prefix#creating-new-admin-user) instead of [setup in the `_users`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html?highlight=users%20prefix#creating-a-new-user) database and assigned the `_admin` permission to prevent any possibility of being locked out.

Each individual database then has a rough level [security policy](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/security.html) of 2 levels:

1. admins
2. members

specified via:

1. names
2. roles

making 4 fields.

These levels control access slightly differently for the 2 types of documents a db can contain:

1. id: `_design/*` - Design documents can contain functions that will be executed in some context
2. id: `other` - Normal documents are just normal data

Both levels of database access have read access to all documents in the database, but admins have write access to _design documents. Write access to normal documents is usually given to all users granted any access to the db, but can be limited by [validate design documents](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions).

#### To Summarize

The process for setting a unique security policy up is:

1. Experience the provided validate design document as a consumer while setting up _users.
2. Setup a new database and its basic security giving your users member access.
3. Add a design doc to the new database with a validate function that restricts member write access.

## 1 Setting up _users entries

### Add a role to a user

As an admin add `role: ["logger"]` to a user's doc and save it, note that this must be done by admin due to this part of the default _users design document:

```
        // DB: _users doc: _design/_auth
        function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) {
        ..
        if (oldRoles.length !== newRoles.length) {
            throw({forbidden: 'Only _admin may edit roles'});
        }
```

### Change the password for the user.

Either the admin or the user can change their password by setting `password:"mynewpassword"` in their document (which couchdb will transform into a hashed/salted password during the save process). This works for a user since they can add/modify fields aside from their name and roles, as long as a user is editing their own doc:

```
        // DB: _users doc: _design/_auth
        function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) {
        ..
        if (userCtx.name !== newDoc.name) {
            throw({
                forbidden: 'You may only update your own user document.'
            });
        }
        // then checks that they don't modify roles
```

You could repeat this process with a user you assign an `adminlogger` role to create a delegated administrator that you assign permissions to can reconfigure a database or you can continue to use the couchdb admin with its `_admin` role for all administration.

## 2 Setup a new database and its basic security

Create a db named logger 
assign the logger a [security policy](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/security.html):

```
{
    "admins": {
        "names": [

        ],
        "roles": [
            "adminlogger"
        ]
    },
    "members": {
        "names": [

        ],
        "roles": [
            "logger"
        ]
    }
}
```

## 3. Create a new [validate design document](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) in the new db

As either _admin user or a user with the `adminlogger` role create a new validate design doc by copying the _users design document, removing the _rev and modifying the function:

```
// DB: logger doc: _design/auth
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) {
     // Don't let non-admins write a pre-existing document:
     if (!is_server_or_database_admin()) {
          if (!!oldDoc) {
              throw({
                forbidden: 'You may not update existing documents.'
            });
          }
     }
     // Where the function to define admins can be copied verbatim from the doc:
     var is_server_or_database_admin = function(userCtx, secObj) {
        // see if the user is a server admin
        if(userCtx.roles.indexOf('_admin') !== -1) {
            return true; // a server admin
        }

        // see if the user a database admin specified by name
        if(secObj && secObj.admins && secObj.admins.names) {
            if(secObj.admins.names.indexOf(userCtx.name) !== -1) {
                return true; // database admin
            }
        }

        // see if the user a database admin specified by role
        if(secObj && secObj.admins && secObj.admins.roles) {
            var db_roles = secObj.admins.roles;
            for(var idx = 0; idx < userCtx.roles.length; idx++) {
                var user_role = userCtx.roles[idx];
                if(db_roles.indexOf(user_role) !== -1) {
                    return true; // role matches!
                }
            }
        }

        return false; // default to no admin
    }
}
```

If you followed these steps then the user you gave the logger role in step 1 can run your code to write new documents only in logger database configured in steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This is embarrasing but I've been scratching my head for a while and cant find the "user docs" you are referring to. my `_users` db only has the design doc (even though I had created users using the permissions window in fauxton)

Comment: @robotHamster it sounds like you were adding _admins instead of normal users? You can create a user in the _usersdb by creating a new document with the fields in 1.7.2.2, you can do it in fauxton as long as you change the _id field from a random one to org.couchdb.user:[username]  (1.7.2.1).